# Validate string of internal type value ? using Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a sequence of numbers which i'm getting from server side .

All i need to do is validate them .I got no trouble doing till now but i am facing issue when i get a `negative number of string type` where the `regex` is breaking

**regex Expression :**

```
^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

Well i tried appending `[\-]` before to make sure negative values work but i am unable to make it work perfectly .

*Example here:*

```
 Value       My Output   Expected 

 1234.5   -   [true]   -  [true]
"1234.5"  -   [true]   -  [true]
"-1234.5" -   [false]  -  [true]
-1234.5   -   [false]  -  [true]
 1234.5   -   [true]   -  [true]
```

I am using the regex code inside a function and passing these values as parameter to it and trying to fetch a Boolean true/false as return .

For regex tester **[click here](https://regex101.com/r/iU3rU5/2)**

Any help on this is appreciated .

Comment: is that the quotes actually present in your input string? Which lang are you running?

Comment: What about the quotes in some examples

Comment: [You can use this](https://regex101.com/r/iU3rU5/4)

Comment: ^[0-9,-]\d*(\.\d+)?$ will handle the negative values, if there are actually quotation marks that is a different story, they should probably just be stripped before proceeding.

Comment: @AvinashRaj i'm using jquery and knockout .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of black magic you used to make `^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$` match `"1234.5"`, but this pattern should do the job:

```
^("?)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\1$
```

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/oG5iZ5/1)

Comment: well i ain't doing anything but it does return true to me . thanks man you regex helps .

Answer (score 1):

You can add an optional `-` at the start of regex as

```
-?\d+(\.\d+)?
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iU3rU5/3)

Comment: its helps appreciate your efforts .

Answer (score 1):

Since the negative sign is optional you need to use the '?' operator.  Try this:

```
^\-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```